# How to plot bar graph in R with each components corresponds with other component?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data frame in following format

```
Triplet Amino_Acid Fraction Freq_1k Number
1      AAA          K     0.62    27.1     39
2      AAC          N     0.32    13.9     20
3      AAG          K     0.38    16.7     24
4      AAT          N     0.68    29.2     42
5      ACA          T     0.21    10.4     15
6      ACC          T     0.31    15.3     22
7      ACG          T     0.28    13.9     20
8      ACT          T     0.20     9.7     14
9      AGA          R     0.17    16.7     24
10     AGC          S     0.18    13.9     20
```

and i want to plot a graph with on x-axis i want Triplet and on y-axis i want Fraction. On plotting a graph i found just 6 Triplets in X-axis but i want to plot fractions according to the number of Triplets like in the above example i have 10 fractions and 10 triplets i want to make a graph with these 10 not with just 6

Comment: What code have you written so far? I'd recommend looking at some beginning ggplot tutorials; any tutorials you find should get you started. Beyond that, this will likely get closed because it is so broad of a question

Comment: `barplot(df$Fraction, names.arg = df$Triplet)`

Comment: @G5W Thank you so much for your help, please see my edit and help me with it

Answer (score 1):

I would use ggplot (check out Hadley Wickham's guide, a full book on data visuals):

https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387981413 (if you are a student you may be able to get it for free)

---

```
library(tidyverse)      # this has ggplot and dplyr

df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(Triplet, Fraction))
```

You can fill that in by your other variables by using whatever you want, within the aesthetic:

```
fill =
```

or

```
color =
```